# How to update Eclipse Kepler to Mars

Tags: eclipse

When I update the Eclipse Kepler to Mars then I receive error like below mentioned, please guide how to update this.

```
An error occurred while uninstalling
session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.eclipse.rcp.configuration_root.win32.win32.x86_64 1.0.0.v20130521-1847 --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).
Backup of file D:\Java\eclipse\eclipse\eclipse.exe failed.
Can not remove : D:\Java\eclipse\eclipse\eclipse.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

In theory updating across major versions should work, but not necessarily across two releases (Kepler -> Mars is skipping Luna).

The recommended way to upgrade across major releases is to download the new version and install it into a separate location, then point it to your existing workspace. If you had third-party plug-ins installed you'll have to re-install them into the new Eclipse (which might require updated versions of those plug-ins, too).

*Do not* extract the new version on top of your existing Eclipse - that won't work and will cause problems.